# Best practices for MobX form not directly updating UI outside form

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have a form for updating a users profile in an app with fields like name, email, etc. In the top right of the screen there is a little dropdown menu with their picture, name, email and options for settings, logout etc.

What is the best practices method within mobx to have the form using the store for state management while also not having the values in this dropdown widget updating as you type?

Right now I just have separate objects in my store: profileFormValues and userData and use profileFormValues for the form and to update the profile and userData to display it elsewhere in the app. When the update is successful, it sets userData to profileFormValues. This feels sloppy and I hope theres some way of doing it more cleanly and keeping the single source of truth of userData

This has almost certainly been asked, but I can't figure out how to word the title to know for sure

Answer (score 3):

[`ViewModel` from the `mobx-utils` package](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils#viewmodel) would fit your use case nicely.

**Example**

```js
const { useState } = React;
const { observable } = mobx;
const { observer } = mobxReactLite;
const { createViewModel } = mobxUtils;

const state = observable({
  email: "foo@bar.com",
  name: "baz"
});

const App = observer(() => {
  const [viewState] = useState(() => createViewModel(state));

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Global state:</h1>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(state)}</div>
      <h2>View state:</h2>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(viewState)}</div>
      <form
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          viewState.submit();
        }}
      >
        <input
          value={viewState.email}
          onChange={(e) => viewState.email = e.target.value}
        />
        <input
          value={viewState.name}
          onChange={(e) => viewState.name = e.target.value}
        />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mobx@6.0.4/dist/mobx.umd.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mobx-react-lite@3.1.6/dist/mobxreactlite.umd.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mobx-utils@6.0.3/mobx-utils.umd.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```